# In Ruby, what is the equivalent to an interface in C#?

Tags: c#, ruby, interface, contract, equivalent

I'm currently trying to learn Ruby and I'm trying to understand more about what it offers in terms of encapsulation and contracts.

In C# a contract can be defined using an interface. A class which implements the interface must fulfil the terms within the contract by providing an implementation for each method and property (and maybe other things) defined. The individual class that implements an interface can do whatever it needs within the scope of the methods defined by the contract, so long as it accepts the same types of arguments and returns the same type of result.

Is there a way to enforce this kind of thing in Ruby?

Thanks

> A simple example of what I mean in C#:
>
> ```
> interface IConsole
> {
>     int MaxControllers {get;}
>     void PlayGame(IGame game);
> }
>
> class Xbox360 : IConsole
> {
>    public int MaxControllers
>    {
>       get { return 4; }
>    }
>
>    public void PlayGame(IGame game)
>    {
>        InsertDisc(game);
>        NavigateToMenuItem();
>        Click();
>    }
> }
>
> class NES : IConsole
> {
>     public int MaxControllers
>     {
>         get { return 2; }
>     }
>
>    public void PlayGame(IGame game)
>    {
>        InsertCartridge(game);
>        TurnOn();
>    }
> }
> ```

Comment: Not having interfaces in a language seems like a horrific design decision to me.

Comment: There *are* interfaces in Ruby (and all languages) -- they're just not a language feature, and hence not enforced by the compiler.  Likewise, I could say that "Not having integers in a language seems like a horrific design decision to me" about C/C++/Java/C#/... -- you're given the tools to build them, if it's important to you.  But most of the time, we just use modular arithmetic on a vanishingly tiny subset of the integers, and our software usually works fine.  Nobody dies.

Comment: pretty sure you forgot to blow on the cartridge before you insert it...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There are no interfaces in ruby since ruby is a dynamically typed language. Interfaces are basically used to make different classes interchangeable without breaking type safety. Your code can work with every Console as long it behaves like a console which in C# means implements IConsole. "duck typing" is a keyword you can use to catch up with the dynamic languages way of dealing with this kind of problem.

Further you can and should write unit tests to verify the behavior of your code. Every object has a `respond_to?` method you can use in your assert.

Comment: Admittedly, it might be useful to be able to say [respond_to? <some interface>], with <some interface> meaning some collection of operations. For a method that expects a list of objects as inputs that supports the expected operations (add, remove, find, length, etc), it could validate that it's input does, indeed, satisfy those requirements without needing to check each one. The object in question wouldn't need to be any type of object, just support the operations declared by "that interface".

Comment: @myself - Seems like it would be entirely possible to define a respond_to? type command validates against an "interface" (list of methods) that just iterates over the methods in the "interface" and returns true if they're all met.

Comment: Being dynamically typed has nothing to do with this. Take a look at php, it's dynamic and has interfaces. Why can't ruby people just accept that there are some features missing in the language? Another feature missing: type hinting.

Comment: @ChocoDeveloper Wat? You can just implement the features you want, if you really need/want them. Ruby allows you to do that, PHP does not.

Answer (score 14):

Ruby has *Interfaces* just like any other language.

Note that you have to be careful not to conflate the concept of the *Interface*, which is an abstract specification of the responsibilities, guarantees and protocols of a unit with the concept of the `interface` which is a keyword in the Java, C# and VB.NET programming languages. In Ruby, we use the former all the time, but the latter simply doesn't exist.

It is very important to distinguish the two. What's important is the *Interface*, not the `interface`. The `interface` tells you pretty much nothing useful. Nothing demonstrates this better than the *marker interfaces* in Java, which are interfaces that have no members at all: just take a look at [`java.io.Serializable`](http://Download.Oracle.Com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) and [`java.lang.Cloneable`](http://Download.Oracle.Com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html); those two `interface`s mean *very* different things, yet they have the *exact same* signature.

So, if two `interface`s that mean different things, have the same signature, what *exactly* is the `interface` even guaranteeing you?

Another good example:

```
interface ICollection<T>: IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable
{
    void Add(T item);
}
```

What is the *Interface* of [`System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<T>.Add`](http://MSDN.Microsoft.Com/library/63ywd54z.aspx)?

- that the length of the collection does not decrease
- that all the items that were in the collection before are still there
- that `item` is in the collection

And which of those actually shows up in the `interface`? None! There is nothing in the `interface` that says that the `Add` method must even *add* at all, it might just as well *remove* an element from the collection.

This is a perfectly valid implementation of that `interface`:

```
class MyCollection<T>: ICollection<T>
{
    void Add(T item)
    {
        Remove(item);
    }
}
```

Another example: where in [`java.util.Set<E>`](http://Download.Oracle.Com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) does it actually say that it is, you know, a *set*? Nowhere! Or more precisely, in the documentation. In English.

In pretty much all cases of `interfaces`, both from Java and .NET, all the *relevant* information is actually in the docs, not in the types. So, if the types don't tell you anything interesting anyway, why keep them at all? Why not stick just to documentation? And that's exactly what Ruby does.

Note that there are *other* languages in which the *Interface* can actually be described in a meaningful way. However, those languages typically don't call the construct which describes the *Interface* "`interface`", they call it `type`. In a dependently-typed programming language, you can for example express the properties that a `sort` function returns a collection of the same length as the original, that every element which is in the original is also in the sorted collection and that no bigger element appears before a smaller element.

So, in short: Ruby does not have an equivalent to a Java `interface`. It *does* however have an equivalent to a Java *Interface*, and its exactly the same as in Java: documentation.

Also, just like in Java, *Acceptance Tests* can be used to specify *Interface*s as well.

In particular, in Ruby, the *Interface* of an object is determined by what it can *do*, not what `class` is is, or what `module` it mixes in. Any object that has a `<<` method can be appended to. This is very useful in unit tests, where you can simply pass in an `Array` or a `String` instead of a more complicated `Logger`, even though `Array` and `Logger` do not share an explicit `interface` apart from the fact that they both have a method called `<<`.

Another example is [`StringIO`](http://RubyDoc.Info/docs/ruby-stdlib/1.9.2/StringIO/), which implements the same *Interface* as `IO` and thus a large portion of the *Interface* of `File`, but without sharing any common ancestor besides `Object`.

Comment: Yes, documentations can describe what a class should do but it doesn't guarantee anything.  With interface implementations you can be sure the Add(item) method is at least present.  Whether or not it performs the function you *expect* it to perform is irrelevant.  You know that if you call Add(item), it will be there and it will do something.  The above sounds like a loosely typed religious argument.

Comment: @Ian if your requirement you're looking to meet via an interface is to ensure that an object has an Add method, respond_to? would be the Ruby way of achieving that.

Comment: I agree with Ian on this, the point of an interface (as embraced in languages such as Java) is to provide a convenient contract for a class. When a class says that it implements an interface, I know for sure that there will be a method called "Add" which i can most likely use to add stuff in. Yes the documentation would also tell me that, but that's not the point. I could have uglified code without any linespace and say "read the documentation" to understand what this class does.
That being said, Tom's comment on using respond_to? would be the way to go. But it is not convenient.

Comment: Why is it not convenient to use respond_to? You can easily write unit tests which just test the interface of a certain class.

Comment: @IanSuttle actually, it's better than that, because the presence of an 'implemented' method indicates an obligation to implement it correctly: that is, if it doesn't do what is expected then the type can objectively be described as 'wrong'. This is precisely why I hold a low opinion of [Structural Typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system), because the intent becomes implicit, not explicit. I think this answer misses the benefits of typed interfaces completely.

Answer (score 5):

Interfaces are usually introduced to static typed OO languages in order to make up for lack of multiple inheritance. In other words, they are more of a necessary evil than something useful *per se*.

Ruby, on the other hand:

1. Is dynamically typed language with "duck typing", so if you want to call method `foo` on two objects, they don't need to neither inherit same ancestor class, nor implement the same interface.
2. Supports multiple inheritance through concept of mixins, again no need for interfaces here.

Comment: composition over inheritance that's the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

Ruby doesn't really have them; interfaces and contracts generally live more in the static world, rather than the dynamic.

There is a gem called [Handshake](http://github.com/bguthrie/handshake) that can implement informal contracts, if you really need it.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby uses the concept of Modules as a stand-in (kinda) for interfaces. Design Patterns in Ruby has a lot of really great examples on the differences between the two concepts and why ruby chooses the more flexible alternative to interfaces.

[http://www.amazon.com/Design-Patterns-Ruby-Russ-Olsen/dp/0321490452](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321490452)

Comment: Interfaces have no functionality, Modules do.

Comment: An interface is not a module. Both are composable, but that's all they have in common.

Answer (score 0):

Jorg has a good point, ruby has interfaces, just not the keyword.  In reading some of the replies, I think this is a negative in dynamic languages.  Instead of enforcing an interface through the language, you must create unit tests instead of having a compiler catch methods not being implemented.  It also makes understanding method harder to reason about, as you have to hunt down what an object is when you are trying to call it.

Take as an example:

```
def my_func(options)
  ...
end
```

If you look at the function, you have no clue what options is and what methods or properties it should call, without hunting for the unit tests, other places it is called, and even look at the method.  Worse yet, the method may not even use those options but pass it to further methods.   Why write unit tests when this should have been caught by a compiler.  The problem is you must write code differently to express this downside in dynamic languages.

There is one upside to this though, and that is dynamic programming languages are FAST to write a piece of code.  I don't have to write any interface declaration and later I can new methods and parameters without going to the interface to expose it.  The trade-offs are speed for maintenance.

Comment: please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) it will be useful to lift your quality up